# Can a visual studio pro prj be saved so that a free version of visual studio can read it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can a visual studio pro 2010 project be saved so that a free version of visual studio can read it ?

I am writing at work and partly at home, my home system has a free version also one of my colleges will use the free version too. Sometimes i need the pro version, when things can not be done with the free version, but not all my projects are like that, and i begin to like pro, so i wonder would it be possible to safe in a format the free 2010 version can understand
(its used for C# and C++ separated projects)

Note these projects are not combinations of C# and C++ in one prj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use any features that aren't available in the free versions, the .sln and .xxproj files are compatible.

For instance in VS 2010, the free versions can't mix C# and C++ in the same .sln. For C++, profile guided optimization is not available. There are probably more examples, but these are the first that come to mind.

If you go for VS 2012, the new desktop edition allows mixing C# and C++.

Comment: Oké thats strange since i had a project made in the free version, just openened it in rpo to look at  some routines didnt change the code (might have saved it dough) and it wont open in the free version where i made it first..?

Comment: Hmm. I have sucessfully exchanged between pro and express with both c# and c++. Maybe it depends on which express editon you use.